# cargo java api to start tomcat; the container is not coming up

Tags: java, tomcat, cargo

I am trying to start tomcat using cargo api. Everything looks fine from the logs, but when i hit the url(http://localhost:8079/), the tomcat management page is not coming up.

Update: I tried starting tomcat from eclipse. The logs say the exact same thing but i am not able to see the management console. so its not an issue with cargo for sure. I get a 404 when i start the server from eclipse .

the code is this

```
LocalConfiguration configuration = (LocalConfiguration) new DefaultConfigurationFactory().createConfiguration(
        "tomcat6x", ContainerType.INSTALLED, ConfigurationType.STANDALONE);
    InstalledLocalContainer container =
        (InstalledLocalContainer) new DefaultContainerFactory().createContainer(
            "tomcat6x", ContainerType.INSTALLED, configuration);
    //container.setHome(installer.getHome());
    //container.setHome("C:\\Users\\Kriss\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\cargo\\installs\\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\\apache-tomcat-7.0.25");

    container.setHome("C:\\TOSCA\\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-x86\\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\\");
    container.setOutput("C:\\TOSCA\\output.log");
    //getting cargo related logging
    container.setLogger(fileLogger);
    //changing the log settings of the container
  //  configuration.setProperty(GeneralPropertySet.LOGGING, LoggingLevel.HIGH.getLevel());

    configuration.setProperty("cargo.servlet.port", "8079");


    logger.info(container.getOutput());
    container.setAppend(false);

    logger.info("gethome value is" + container.getHome());

 // (3) Statically deploy some WAR (optional)
  //  configuration.addDeployable(new WAR("cargo.war"));
 // (4) Start the container
    container.start();
    logger.info("Container is started");
    Thread.sleep(26000);
    container.stop();
    logger.info("Container is stopped");
```

The logs look fine(atleast to me :P)

```
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [C:\Users\Kriss\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\conf\common\classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [C:\Users\Kriss\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\conf\common\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [C:\Users\Kriss\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\conf\shared\classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [C:\Users\Kriss\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\conf\shared\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network Adapter\Driver;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;.
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector} Setting property 'emptySessionPath' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8079"]
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 674 ms
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.25
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\Kriss\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\conf\conf\Catalina\localhost\manager.xml
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Users\Kriss\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\conf\webapps\cargocpc.war
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\Kriss\AppData\Local\Temp\cargo\conf\webapps\host-manager
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8079"]
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 10, 2012 4:27:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 610 ms


Minor detail: when i tried to start, bootstrap was missing some classes which were part of tomcat-juli.jar. so i unjarred that and put the classes inside bootstrap.jar. I just thought i should mention that as a side comment though i dont think it is causing some problem.. 

Also here is the log when i start tomcat using command prompt:

Apr 09, 2012 1:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.22.
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [false], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], r
andom [true].
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1944 ms
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.25
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\TOSCA\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-
x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\docs
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\TOSCA\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-
x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\examples
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\TOSCA\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-
x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\host-manager
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\TOSCA\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-
x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\manager
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\TOSCA\apache-tomcat-7.0.25-windows-
x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.25\webapps\ROOT
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:38 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 09, 2012 1:55:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 927 ms
```

Comment: Did you try port 8080? Does it work, if you start tomcat via its batch file?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, i tried with 8080 and it dint work. so i tried with 8079 and same problem..

Comment: And if you start it with its start script?

Comment: If i start using normal start script(startcmd.bat), everything is working fine as expected and i can hit the url as well! thanks again !